# Hive: How to create multiple tables from multiple files or count entries per file

Tags: hive, hiveql

My goal is to combine entries from multiple files into 1 table but am having some trouble getting there.

So I understand that you can add all entries into a table by doing:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename
(
    teams STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///hive-data';
```

Where each text file's data looks something like:

```
student#A18645
student#V86541
student#X78543
```

However, with the code above, this combines all the data from N number of files together in my directory which makes it hard to combine the data. What I want is to have the first entries from all files be concatenated together into a single string and entered into a new table and so forth.
I have tried to number each entry using ROW_NUMBER() but that does not give the number of their place in the file but rather in the table itself.

Therefore, is there a way I can create a table per file, number the entries, and join all the tables together so that in the end, I can get a table that looks like:

```
number           students
1                student#A18645,student#D94655,...student#S45892
2                student#V86541,student#D45645,...student#F46444
3                student#X78543,student#T78722,...student#M99846
```

Or rather, a way to number each entry as the line number of the file it came from so I can do an inner join on my table.

Note: the number of files can vary so I do not have a set number of files to loop through

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to build the final table.

**Let's say that these are two files for two teams.**

```
-- team1.txt
student#A18645
student#V86541
student#X78543

-- team2.txt
student#P20045
student#Q30041
student#R40043
```

**Load them in HDFS, each file into a separate directory**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data/team1
hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data/team2
hadoop fs -put team1.txt /hive-data/team1
hadoop fs -put team2.txt /hive-data/team2
```

**Create two tables in Hive, one for each team**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE team1
(
    teams STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 'hdfs:////hive-data/team1';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE team2
(
    teams STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 'hdfs:////hive-data/team2';
```

**Create the final table in Hive to hold combined data**

```
CREATE TABLE teams
(
    team_number INT,
    students STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Populate the final table**
*(Since comma is a field delimiter, colon is used to generate the string of list of students)*

```
INSERT INTO teams (team_number, students)
SELECT 1, CONCAT_WS(":", COLLECT_LIST(teams)) FROM team1;

INSERT INTO teams (team_number, students)
SELECT 2, CONCAT_WS(":", COLLECT_LIST(teams)) FROM team2;
```

**Verify the final table**

```
SELECT * FROM teams;
teams.team_number   teams.students
1                   student#A18645:student#V86541:student#X78543
2                   student#P20045:student#Q30041:student#R40043
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is kind of what I wanted to avoid because I dont always know what files there are in the folder so i cant create a set number of tables or know their direct path. I just want to be able to sort of loop through a given directory and for each file in there, create a table. If that makes sense.

Comment: You can write a simple shell script for automating this flow. The script will take one parameter - the directory that contains the team files. It will generate a file list, and for each file: (1) Create an HDFS directory (2) Load the file in the HDFS directory (3) Create the team Hive table (4) Populate the teams table.

Comment: Does the approach of a shell script to automatically handle files in a directory work for your situation @deeformvp?